# How do I use robocopy to run a powershell elevated copy with spaces in the directory names?

Tags: powershell

If you find a better question that encompasses my situation, please let me know. I haven't found my case yet.

I tried running an elevated powershell command with:

```
powershell -command "somecommand -Verb runas"
```

as

```
powershell -command "robocopy \\hostess\blab\foo 'C:\Program Files\foo ' /s /e /r:0 /z -Verb runas"
```

The robocopy part works by itself but then adding powershell causes:

```
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #7 : "-Verb"
```

Comment: Your issue isn't anything unique, or out of the ordinary, at all, you simply have not put your single and double quotes in the appropriate locations. As such your question is simply a typo, lack of using the correct syntax, `powershell.exe -Command "robocopy.exe '\\hostess\blab\foo' 'C:\Program Files\foo' /E /Z /R:0" -Verb RunAs`. It is therefore off topic and of no future use to our readership.

Comment: @Compo I believe your wording to be quite direct so much so that it might damage this safe space for learners. As it is in the common interest to sponsor the asking of questions by both experts AND juniors, I wish for you edit or replace your comment with one that is more appropriate for this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb is a parameter of powershell executable and not part of the command parameter

```
powershell -command "robocopy \\hostess\blab\foo 'C:\Program Files\foo ' /s /e /r:0 /z" -Verb runas
```

see also https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-elevate.html